# IIS Redirect Message

Tags: iis-6

I am getting ready to move some web application from an IIS 6 server to another server and I would like to setup the old server so that if a person browses to any URL within that application they will get a page with the new URL which includes the path and query string parameters. I know how to do this as a redirect in IIS, but I can't find a way to have it displayed in a page.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is set up a "Go somewhere else" alert instead of a redirect, the first thing that comes to my mind is to remove everything from the old server, and serve up a custom 404 page.

Comment: How would I setup the 404 page to display the new URL? For example for http://oldserver/apps/page.aspx?parm=1 I want to display http://newserver/page.aspx?param=1.

Comment: I could write an answer up about parameters in a 404, but I think the guys at StackOverflow did a better job with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650340/how-to-keep-parameters-on-url-when-write-a-custom-404-error-page